# Cloud Build unable to retreive Build logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I have GCP Cloud Build pipelines running to completion but when I go to the console I get `No log to display, unable to retreive build log`. This weird considering I had access to the logs for the previous builds. This seemed to have just changed overnight. Kindly offer insights and direction. [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Build - View logs permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362244/google-cloud-build-view-logs-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't see the logs could be the permission over the bucket used to store them, the logs are being written in a text file in a Cloud Storage bucket. Now, if you do not specify which bucket that will be in the configuration file (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#logsbucket) then Cloud Build uses a Google managed bucket to store the log. If you specify your own Cloud Storage bucket then you can go to that bucket’s permissions in the console and add the users you want as members with the “Storage Object Viewer” role. This way they will have access to that bucket’s objects which will contain the logs of Cloud Build.

Answer (score 0):

Since they changed the UI I’ve ran into this issue a few times here and there when clicking on links from our slack notifications.  I’ve solved it by a refresh or by going back into the build.