# Cloud Build - view cloud build and it's builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to configure cloud build for a customer but I'm not sure how grant some people only the viewer access for this app. My goal is to have a cloud build configured for their github testing and they should be able to view each run.
If I give them `roles/cloudbuild.builds.viewer` then they cannot view inside a particular build and see how their test run.
I can give them the `roles/viewer` role but this is not what I need as they can also view everything else in the project.
I know there was an issue with this in the past [Google Cloud Build - View logs permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362244/google-cloud-build-view-logs-permissions) but maybe there was some fix created over the years?
Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to see the log, grant the user log viewer: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#logging.viewer

Comment: Great, I added an answer to help others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share the logs of Cloud build, you must grant the user as Cloud logging Viewer to allow them to access the logs. Use the [`logging.viewer` role](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#logging.viewer) for that